# Laravel Blade if statement with input button

Tags: laravel, input, laravel-blade

Does somebody know how to correcly create an input button using Laravel Blade? I needs to alternate between a active and inactive stated. That's why I'm using an if-statement.

This is my code for creating a input button inside a tabledata `<td>`.

```
@if ({{ $customer->active }})

        <input type="button" name="active" value="Active">

@else   

        <input type="button" name="active" value="Inactive">

@endif
```

Error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (View:...)

**Result** (After implementing solution)

```
<td>
        <input type="button" id="active" name="active" 
        value="{{ $customer->active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}">

</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just want to toggle the value of the button right? Why not just `<input type="button" name="active" value="{{ $customer->active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}">`

Answer (score 1):

If active is false, it wont print 0, thus you'll get this error.

```
{{ ($customer->active ? '1' : '0') }}
```

should work I think

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't think you need an echo. Blade renders it correcly.

Comment: Can you, for my learning and knowledge, test if my updated answer works? furthermore, shigg answer is better :)

Comment: hank you for the feedback! shigg's answer is what I would suggest you to use however :)